# How do you remove the Next and Prev buttons from virtual keyboard in Sencha Touch / Phonegap application

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, extjs, sencha-touch

So I have this Phonegap application built using Sencha Touch.  I have a textarea control for users to type in some information.  When the box gets focus it brings up the virtual keyboard. But the virtual keyboard has next previous and done buttons on it.

How to I remove the next and previous buttons? They don't seem to do anything anyway.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a way!! This guy has done it by making modifications in the AppDelegate.m. You can find description at this [link](http://ios-blog.co.uk/articles/tutorials/rich-text-editing-a-simple-start-part-1/) under bonus code section.
You can also refer the code for same developed by Kerri Shotts [Code Here](https://github.com/photokandyStudios/GreekInterlinearBible/blob/master/GreekInterlinearBible/Classes/AppDelegate.m#L83)

Now that the done button is gone i am trying to figure out how to make the keyboard disappear. This will be everybody's next step.

Answer (score 2):

The previous next are for tabbing to previous or next fields on the page. It has a name and is called "Form Assistant", I think it's default to Safari, and PhoneGap essentially is a wrapper around Safari.

AFAIK , there is no way to remove it. Of course, the previous next buttons get disabled, if there is only one field as it's seems to be in your case

EDIT: As from the new comments, it seems there's a way in the new PhoneGap versions. FYI

Comment: I was kind of worried that was the case.  Doing a quick search for "Form Assistant" showed people with the same issue.  Oh well, thanks for your help!

Comment: Check the answer given by [Rahul Kahale](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6073846/how-do-you-remove-the-next-and-prev-buttons-from-virtual-keyboard-in-sencha-touc#10468840)

Comment: there is a way to do it now with phonegap
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8718411/how-do-i-install-this-script-into-phonegap-for-ios

Answer (score 1):

you can try this [Plugin](https://github.com/don/KeyboardToolbarRemover/blob/6685b402469a06911fed93ed8d4e3796f8904075/README.md) Created By don. to show/hide keyboard toolbar.

It worked like charm from my side.