# how to remove prev next button from virtual keyboard IOS

Tags: objective-c, keyboard, ios5, uiwebview

i have use a UIWebview in IOS 5. I try to set `contenteditable="true"` to make uiwebview editable.

The screenshoot of my app is similar to an image in this link [How do you remove the Next and Prev buttons from virtual keyboard in Sencha Touch / Phonegap application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6073846/how-do-you-remove-the-next-and-prev-buttons-from-virtual-keyboard-in-sencha-touc),

[image]

my problem is i want to remove this prev & next button from the keyboard, but i dont know how. Can some body help me?

thank you

Comment: I found the solution for iOS 8. You can check it here: iOS 8 - Remove Previous/Next/Done UIKeyboard Toolbar inside a UIWebView      http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25022089/remove-next-previous-buttons-inputaccessoryview-for-custom-keyboard-in-ios8

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**This is an old answer and is no longer working on iOS 9. For an updated solution, see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19042279/983912).**

---

It is a gray-area, but certainly possible.

See here: http://ios-blog.co.uk/iphone-development-tutorials/rich-text-editing-a-simple-start-part-1/

Register for notification on keyboard showing:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
```

Then:

```
- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)note {
    [self performSelector:@selector(removeBar) withObject:nil afterDelay:0];
}

- (void)removeBar {
    // Locate non-UIWindow.
    UIWindow *keyboardWindow = nil;
    for (UIWindow *testWindow in [[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows]) {
        if (![[testWindow class] isEqual:[UIWindow class]]) {
            keyboardWindow = testWindow;
            break;
        }
    }

    // Locate UIWebFormView.
    for (UIView *possibleFormView in [keyboardWindow subviews]) {       
        // iOS 5 sticks the UIWebFormView inside a UIPeripheralHostView.
        if ([[possibleFormView description] rangeOfString:@"UIPeripheralHostView"].location != NSNotFound) {
            for (UIView *subviewWhichIsPossibleFormView in [possibleFormView subviews]) {
                if ([[subviewWhichIsPossibleFormView description] rangeOfString:@"UIWebFormAccessory"].location != NSNotFound) {
                    [subviewWhichIsPossibleFormView removeFromSuperview];
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it left an empty area where the bar was, how do you remove that?

Comment: You can try lower the contentInset.

Comment: hm, I haven't tried your way, but I found that if I set the frame of the accessory form to an "empty rectangle" it works.

Comment: Is this accessing the private API to remove the next/previous in your code?

Comment: As I said, it's a gray area. Technically, it is not private. But we are touching Apple's view hierarchy.

Comment: @Rajneesh071 See my solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19033292/ios-7-uiwebview-keyboard-issue/19042279#19042279

Comment: Yes, we are using it in our product.

Comment: Thanks..working fine.. but how to remove other button's like bold,undo , redo etc

Answer (score 3):

Remove the empty area.

```
- (void)removeBar {
    // Locate non-UIWindow.
    UIWindow *keyboardWindow = nil;
    for (UIWindow *testWindow in [[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows]) {
        if (![[testWindow class] isEqual:[UIWindow class]]) {
            keyboardWindow = testWindow;
            break;
        }
    }

    // Locate UIWebFormView
    for (UIView *possibleFormView in [keyboardWindow subviews]) {
        if ([[possibleFormView description] hasPrefix:@"<UIPeripheralHostView"]) {
            for (UIView* peripheralView in [possibleFormView subviews]) {

                // hides the backdrop (iOS 7)
                if ([[peripheralView description] hasPrefix:@"<UIKBInputBackdropView"]) {
                    //skip the keyboard background....hide only the toolbar background
                    if ([peripheralView frame].origin.y == 0){
                        [[peripheralView layer] setOpacity:0.0];
                    }
                }
                // hides the accessory bar
                if ([[peripheralView description] hasPrefix:@"<UIWebFormAccessory"]) {
                    // remove the extra scroll space for the form accessory bar
                    UIScrollView *webScroll;
                    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 5.0) {
                        webScroll = [[self webView] scrollView];
                    } else {
                        webScroll = [[[self webView] subviews] lastObject];
                    }
                    CGRect newFrame = webScroll.frame;
                    newFrame.size.height += peripheralView.frame.size.height;
                    webScroll.frame = newFrame;

                    // remove the form accessory bar
                    [peripheralView removeFromSuperview];
                }
                // hides the thin grey line used to adorn the bar (iOS 6)
                if ([[peripheralView description] hasPrefix:@"<UIImageView"]) {
                    [[peripheralView layer] setOpacity:0.0];
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's the `inputAccessoryView` for `UIWebBrowserView` (inner `UIWebView`), you can hack it.

Here is an example: https://gist.github.com/bjhomer/2048571

Comment: Much cleaner than the previous solutions.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution for iOS 8. You can check it here:

```
-(void) removeKeyboard {
UIWindow *keyboardWindow = nil;
for (UIWindow *testWindow in [[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows]) {
    if (![[testWindow class] isEqual : [UIWindow class]]) {
        keyboardWindow = testWindow;
        break;
    }
}
// Locate UIWebFormView.
for (UIView *possibleFormView in [keyboardWindow subviews]) {

    if ([[possibleFormView description] hasPrefix : @"<UIInputSetContainerView"]) {
        for (UIView* peripheralView in possibleFormView.subviews) {

            for (UIView* peripheralView_sub in peripheralView.subviews) {


                // hides the backdrop (iOS 8)
                if ([[peripheralView_sub description] hasPrefix : @"<UIKBInputBackdropView"] && peripheralView_sub.frame.size.height == 44) {
                    [[peripheralView_sub layer] setOpacity : 0.0];

                }
                // hides the accessory bar
                if ([[peripheralView_sub description] hasPrefix : @"<UIWebFormAccessory"]) {


                    for (UIView* UIInputViewContent_sub in peripheralView_sub.subviews) {

                        CGRect frame1 = UIInputViewContent_sub.frame;
                        frame1.size.height = 0;
                        peripheralView_sub.frame = frame1;
                        UIInputViewContent_sub.frame = frame1;
                        [[peripheralView_sub layer] setOpacity : 0.0];

                    }

                    CGRect viewBounds = peripheralView_sub.frame;
                    viewBounds.size.height = 0;
                    peripheralView_sub.frame = viewBounds;

                }
            }

        }
    }
}
}
```

You may try and improve this. try call this function inside Your UIKeyboardDidShowNotification event handler.

Hope this helps...
This is the level of views in accessory:
(UIWebFormAccessory) -> (UIToolbar) -> (UIImageView,UIToolbarButton,UIToolbarButton)