# Hiding Keyboard accessorybar in WKWebView

Tags: ios, xcode, uiwebview, wkwebview

How can I hide keyboard accessory bar in WKWebview? Although there are some resources for UIWebView, I haven't been able to find one for WkWebview on Stackoverflow.

Related:

1. [Removing the accesory item on the UIWebView keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9970832/removing-the-accesory-item-on-the-uiwebview-keyboard)
2. [iOS 7 UIWebView keyboard issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19033292/ios-7-uiwebview-keyboard-issue/)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is possible in `WKWebView` with a variant of [the method for swizzling out the `inputAccessoryView` on `UIWebView`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19033292/ios-7-uiwebview-keyboard-issue/19042279#19042279).

First, add this little class:

```
@interface _NoInputAccessoryView : NSObject

@end

@implementation _NoInputAccessoryView

- (id)inputAccessoryView {
    return nil;
}

@end
```

Next, add this method:

```
- (void)removeInputAccessoryViewFromWKWebView:(WKWebView *)webView {
    UIView *targetView;

    for (UIView *view in webView.scrollView.subviews) {
        if([[view.class description] hasPrefix:@"WKContent"]) {
            targetView = view;
        }
    }

    if (!targetView) {
        return;
    }

    NSString *noInputAccessoryViewClassName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_NoInputAccessoryView", targetView.class.superclass];
    Class newClass = NSClassFromString(noInputAccessoryViewClassName);

    if(newClass == nil) {
        newClass = objc_allocateClassPair(targetView.class, [noInputAccessoryViewClassName cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding], 0);
        if(!newClass) {
            return;
        }

        Method method = class_getInstanceMethod([_NoInputAccessoryView class], @selector(inputAccessoryView));

        class_addMethod(newClass, @selector(inputAccessoryView), method_getImplementation(method), method_getTypeEncoding(method));

        objc_registerClassPair(newClass);
    }

    object_setClass(targetView, newClass);
}
```

Then all you have to do is call that method and pass in your `WKWebView`:

```
[self removeInputAccessoryViewFromWKWebView:webView];
```

Note: I do not yet know for sure if this will pass app review, but it is *extremely* similar to the same code I used for `UIWebView`, and that did pass review.

**Update:** This code is in an app that has passed App Store review.

Comment: This only applies to UIWebView, no?

Comment: No, this solution is specifically for WKWebView, although it was adapted from a technique for UIWebView.

Comment: @JustinMichael , any idea how can we port this to Swift ?

Comment: Swift version of this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33853924/removing-wkwebview-accesory-bar-in-swift/33939584#33939584

Comment: Brilliant! In the class you are adding the method, you must include <objc/runtime.h>

Comment: Will Apple will approve this?

Comment: @PauloCesar Yes, this code is being used in an app in the App Store.

Comment: Will this also not remove the "Done" button from <select> listboxes?

Comment: @AdamLeggett Yep. You’ll need to provide an alertanitive to the missing Done button for form controls if you get rid of the accessory view.

Comment: @JustinMichael is there a reasonable way to only disable the accessory view for keyboards?

Comment: @AdamLeggett Not that I've been able to find.  It's probably possible, but would take a lot of work to figure out.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. That kind of leaves the solution incomplete without something to replace that "Done" button.

Comment: @JustinMichael This code works perfectly on iPhone but on iPad I still see the inputAccessory view. Do you have experience of this code running on iPad ?

Comment: @Pollizzio This has worked great on both iPhone and iPad for me.  What version of iOS are you using on the iPad?

Comment: @JustinMichael I'm trying with 11.4, I found that, on iPad only, the AccessoryView disappears if I do webView.inputAssistantItem.trailingBarButtonGroups/leadingBarButtonGroups = [NSMutableArray new];

Comment: This is based on my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19042279/983912

Would have appreciated a reference.

Comment: @LeoNatan Sorry about that. I thought I linked to your answer when I originally posted, but I must have forgotten.  Updated the answer to link to your answer.  Thanks for calling that out!

Comment: You can subclass `WKWebView` in iOS13+, and override the property: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58001395/344591