# WKWebView based app crashes when using Dictation

Tags: ios

I'm busting my head off here trying to understand why my app ( `WKWebView` based app ) is crashing when I hit the dictation button.

```html
Thread : Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x19a55a5f4 _class_getNonMetaClass + 212
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x19a556ccc _class_resolveMethod + 112
2  libobjc.A.dylib                0x19a55f9a8 lookUpImpOrForward + 360
3  libobjc.A.dylib                0x19a55f80c lookUpImpOrNil + 12
4  libobjc.A.dylib                0x19a557048 class_respondsToSelector + 40
5  Foundation                     0x1867fb004 +[NSBundle bundleForClass:] + 80
6  UIKit                          0x18b1b038c -[UIView(UIDebugging) description] + 212
7  Foundation                     0x1867f698c _NSDescriptionWithLocaleFunc + 108
8  CoreFoundation                 0x18596f994 __CFStringAppendFormatCore + 8272
9  CoreFoundation                 0x18596d90c _CFStringCreateWithFormatAndArgumentsAux2 + 244
10 Foundation                     0x1867f68e0 -[NSPlaceholderString initWithFormat:locale:arguments:] + 168
11 Foundation                     0x1867f67b0 +[NSString stringWithFormat:] + 68
12 UIKit                          0x18b6a47f8 -[UIDictationController insertSerializedDictationResult:withCorrectionIdentifier:] + 144
13 UIKit                          0x18b6a4e44 __98-[UIDictationController finishDictationRecognitionWithPhrases:languageModel:correctionIdentifier:]_block_invoke + 420
14 UIKit                          0x18b6a3e60 -[UIDictationController performIgnoringDocumentChanges:] + 48
15 UIKit                          0x18b6a20a8 -[UIDictationController _runFinalizeOperation] + 48
16 UIKit                          0x18b6a23a0 -[UIDictationController setState:] + 504
17 UIKit                          0x18b6a4bd0 -[UIDictationController finishDictationRecognitionWithPhrases:languageModel:correctionIdentifier:] + 552
18 UIKit                          0x18b6a50c0 -[UIDictationController dictationConnection:didRecognizePhrases:languageModel:correctionIdentifier:] + 204
19 AssistantServices              0x18cd81bd4 -[AFDictationConnection _tellSpeechDelegateDidRecognizeSpeechPhrases:languageModel:correctionIdentifier:] + 188
20 AssistantServices              0x18cd841a4 __101-[AFDictationConnectionServiceDelegate speechDidRecognizePhrases:usingSpeechModel:correctionContext:]_block_invoke + 76
21 libdispatch.dylib              0x19ad756e8 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
22 libdispatch.dylib              0x19ad756a8 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
23 libdispatch.dylib              0x19ad7adb0 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1844
24 CoreFoundation                 0x18595c1f8 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 12
25 CoreFoundation                 0x18595a060 __CFRunLoopRun + 1628
26 CoreFoundation                 0x185888ca0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 384
27 GraphicsServices               0x190ac4088 GSEventRunModal + 180
28 UIKit                          0x18afa0ffc UIApplicationMain + 204
29 ChatApp                        0x10004f2a0 main (AppDelegate.swift:16)
30 libdyld.dylib                  0x19ada68b8 start + 4
```

Any idea ? Anybody encountering the same issue ? You have the `CrashLytics` log upper.

Answer (score 0):

Late to this party, but I tracked down a similar crash that occurred when messing with `WKWebView`'s input accessory using the approach [outlined in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33853924/removing-wkwebview-accesory-bar-in-swift). Leaving the input accessory as-is prevents the crash during dictation.

If this is the case you're seeing [I've outlined a workaround here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33853924/removing-wkwebview-accesory-bar-in-swift#comment75309120_33939584).