# Incorrect placement of autocorrect bubbles

Tags: ios, wkwebview

I'm building a web-based native chat, and I'm running into some issues with the autocorrect suggestion bubbles.

As you can see in the following image, the suggestions get placed underneath the keyboard.

[image]

The view is a React webapp inside a `WKWebView`, only the navigation bar is native. The webview bottom is constrained to the keyboards top. I've used [this hack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33853924/removing-wkwebview-accesory-bar-in-swift/47553034#47553034) to remove the input accessory.

**Is there any way to force the suggestion bubble to be placed above and not below the input text field?**

Comment: This question is really missing a lot of important detail. How is your webview constructed? What do the components look like that are used to set it up? When you say **constrained to the keyboard's top**, does the webview include the input field? What kind of styles are you applying to those elements?

Comment: Could you show us some code?

Comment: Please show your component if you want any specific help. The best I can do with the little you gave is to ask if you've tried the React-Native iOS keyboard avoiding view https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/keyboardavoidingview.html

Comment: That's really not relevant in this question.