# How to remove keyboard bar with buttons Previous and Next and Done on UIWebView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiwebview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to remove prev next button from virtual keyboard IOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8470984/how-to-remove-prev-next-button-from-virtual-keyboard-ios)

I am opening keyboard in my `UIWebView` but as per the default structure of `UIWebView` I am getting Bar with Previous, Next and Done `button` on the top of keyboard.

It consumes much space in my app so, I want to remove that bar.

How can I remove that bar?

Answer (score 0):

```
Register for notification on keyboard showing:

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
Then:

- (void)removeBar
{
    // Locate non-UIWindow.
    UIWindow *keyboardWindow = nil;
    for (UIWindow *testWindow in [[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows])
    {
        if (![[testWindow class] isEqual:[UIWindow class]])
        {
            keyboardWindow = testWindow;
            break;
        }
    }

    // Locate UIWebFormView.
    for (UIView *possibleFormView in [keyboardWindow subviews])
    {
        // iOS 5 sticks the UIWebFormView inside a UIPeripheralHostView.
        if ([[possibleFormView description] rangeOfString:@"UIPeripheralHostView"].location != NSNotFound)
        {
            for (UIView *subviewWhichIsPossibleFormView in [possibleFormView subviews])
            {
                if ([[subviewWhichIsPossibleFormView description] rangeOfString:@"UIWebFormAccessory"].location != NSNotFound)
                {
                    [subviewWhichIsPossibleFormView removeFromSuperview];
                }
            }
        }
        else if ([[possibleFormView description] rangeOfString:@"UIImageView"].location != NSNotFound)
        {
            [possibleFormView removeFromSuperview]; //remove shadow above bar. If it doesn't remove shadow then set possibleFormView's frame as CGRectZero
        }
    }
}
```