# UIKeyboardDidShowNotification event fires even when external keyboard is present

Tags: ios, uikeyboard

I need to know whether or not an external keyboard is connected.  I'm familiar with using NSNotificationCenter and getting the UIKeyboardDidShowNotification event to determine if the virtual keyboard was displayed.  The problem I'm having is when an external keyboard is attached and you click in a text field a small view shows up on the bottom with 'prev' and 'next' buttons.  The UIKeyboardDidShowNotification event fires when this happens even when there is an external keyboard connected.  Thus even when an external keyboard is connected it appears as if the virtual keyboard is being displayed.

Is there anyway to disable this small view with 'prev' and 'next' buttons from being displayed and hopefully the UIKeyboardDidShowNotification event is not fired.

Otherwise it doesn't seem possible to use the NSNotificationCenter in a reliable way to determine if the keyboard is connected or not.  I surely don't want to use the private API's for detecting if a keyboard is connected.

Comment: Does the virtual keyboard display while the external keyboard is connected? I'm confused about how this previous and next bar is displaying? That isn't possible in iOS unless it's customized... or are you in a UIWebView clicking on an input field online?

Comment: Yes, I am in a UIWebView clicking in an input field.  I have nothing customized.  I've seen a keyboard that doesn't have a tab key although my keyboard does.  The prev and next buttons peform the tab and back-tab keystrokes.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the best solution I could find.... if a blank space is left they have instructions for that in the comments below the answer as well: [how to remove prev next button from virtual keyboard IOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8470984/how-to-remove-prev-next-button-from-virtual-keyboard-ios)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be looking to bypass normal device behavior in order to do hardware detection. Forget trying to make the event not fire. Instead look at what is different when it fires with an external vs. onscreen keyboard.

From debugging, I've noticed that the view will not be sized any differently regardless of whether or not an external keyboard is connected. Instead, the origin of the view changes so that only the top toolbar of the keyboard is drawn within the bounds of the screen.

```
- (void)keyboardDidShow:(NSNotification *)notification {

    NSDictionary *userInfo = [notification userInfo];
    CGRect kbRect = [[userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];

    if(kbRect.origin.x != 0 || kbRect.origin.y != 0) {
        //external keyboard
    }
    else {
        //onscreen keyboard
    }
}
```

The above should work, but you could always debug your application and change up the 'if' statement in order to better suit your needs. For instance, since I only allow landscape layout, I only have to check `kbRect.origin.x`, but instead of checking that it's non-zero, I used numbers I got from debugging.

I guess this is a year late, but I came across this question while researching and figured it still deserves a good answer.