# Remove the toolbar from the UIKeyboard inside of a UIWebView iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, uikeyboard

I have seen multiple methods to "remove the previous/next/done toolbar" from the keyboard, but each time I tried implementing the code snippets it never worked.

I'm fairly sure it's because a lot of these were to be used within phonegap, and I'm trying to avoid phonegap all together, I just want a native iOS 7 solution to remove the keyboard's toolbar from inside a UIWebView.

Obviously it's possible when using phonegap, but is there way to do this without phonegap?

I remember testing things over here...
[how to remove prev next button from virtual keyboard IOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8470984/how-to-remove-prev-next-button-from-virtual-keyboard-ios)
...but none of that was working for me. Maybe someone has advice to lead me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Actually...

After reading this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19604918/3138300

I noticed that by changing [self webView] to [webView self] it worked flawlessly. Not sure why, but hey - I'll accept it.

Nevermind, I succesfully removed the toolbar in my app with this method plus what I did to change the code to actually build.