# iOS Virtual Keyboard. Remove prev next buttons, keeping although the Done button in top keyboard on PhoneGap app

Tags: ios, cordova, keyboard, customization

I have removed the black bar from the keyboard as the next link said, but for realistic usage, i want to keep the bar only with "Done" button available. Do somebody know if this is possible in iOS, or just to remove the whole bar from the keyboard.

[How do you remove the Next and Prev buttons from virtual keyboard in Sencha Touch / Phonegap application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6073846/how-do-you-remove-the-next-and-prev-buttons-from-virtual-keyboard-in-sencha-touc)

Than you.